# Cannot rewrite bootstrap properties

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've included bootstrap.min.css file in my index.html and then my own style.css file. I try to rewrite some properties from Bootstrap, but it doesn't work! I can't imagine why it works that way. Help me, please!

Pin the code and the screenshot below. Thanks a lot!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
...
 <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html">Food, LLC</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
.navbar-brand {
color: black; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, Bootstrap.js does some DOM manipulation, so its always better to override rules than to replace the rules

```css
.custom{
color: black; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand custom" href="./index.html">TEST</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work for me :( The result is the same as previous was.

Comment: then it must be some other rules you've defined elsewhere, can you share your entire markup?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eykq4tkt/2/  this should have been the accepted answer. the logic is correct and it works check updated fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe

```
navbar-header.navbar-brand { color: black; }
```

in your css

Comment: Becouse it has better path then single class

Answer (score -1):

Try using !important like that: color:black !important;
But it might be bad practice, so try specifying which tag exactly you wanna change:
using in the css, for example div ul li a{color:black;} will always be executed better than just a{color:black;}
:) Hope this helps